# Element UI +vueJs, how to change the table sorting caret icon

Tags: vue.js, element-ui

i am building an app with element UI and when using tables with sorting capabilities, i can't change the sorting caret, bby default it's a filled triangle but i want to change it to an SVG icon i have.

here is the default icon :
[image]

Is there a way to change it, as the official docs don't specify how, or give any slot for it in headers.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you can't change it, looking at the interface you can see that it receives four parameters, but the documentation indicates two.

Documentation

```
:default-sort="{ prop: 'date', order: 'descending' }"
```

Interface

```
interface Sort {
    prop: string;
    order: 'ascending' | 'descending';
    init?: any;
    silent?: any;
}
```

if you manage to do it, I'm interested in knowing how you did it.